# Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.aplicationContextInitializer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Class with main method:

```
   package ftn.project.eObrazovanje;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class EObrazovanjeApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(EObrazovanjeApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ftn.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>eObrazovanje</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>eObrazovanje</name>
    <description>Projekat iz predmeta tehnologije i sistemi eObrazovanja</description>

      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And I have this error when I try to run as Spring boot application:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:381)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at ftn.project.eObrazovanje.EObrazovanjeApplication.main(EObrazovanjeApplication.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:376)
    ... 6 more
```

In pom file I just changed versions of jars that I imported (as now that I post), but still have the same problem...
I downloaded this project from friends Github, now I just trying to run on my laptop.
At my friend laptop it works without any problem.

Comment: A `NoSuchMethodException` almost always means that you have mismatched versions in some of your libraries. First try using the current version of Boot 1 (1.5.14), and if that doesn't work post the output of `dependency:resolve`.

Comment: Can you post the other classes as well? The ones that actually do some stuff. Also try increasing the version of parent to 2.0.2